# How can I compute current speed, average speed and total distance with leafletjs?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I have a tracking map using Leaflet.js and I want to display:

a) current speed,

b) average speed and

c) total distance traveled.

How would I do this? https://jsfiddle.net/chovy/rfvtwed5/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css"
    />
    <style>
      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        width: 95vw;
        height: 90vh;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      header {
        padding: 1rem 0;
      }

      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .marker img {
        width: 3rem;
      }

      .marker span {
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        width: 10rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 0.4rem;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      @media (max-width: 481px) {
        /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */
        #status {
          display: block;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <button id="start">start</button>
      <button id="stop">stop</button>
      <button id="marker">add marker</button>
      <button id="export">export</button>
      <span id="status"></span>
    </header>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <script>
      const exportButton = document.getElementById("export");
      let intv;

      const status = document.getElementById("status");

      var map = L.map("map", {
        center: [9.082, 8.6753],
        zoom: 8,
      });
      var osm = L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          attribution:
                                '&copy; <a href="https://skatespot.com">SkateSpot, Inc.</a>',
        }
      ).addTo(map);
      L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("Your browser doesn't support geolocation feature!");
      }

      const trackingPath = [];
      const polyline = L.polyline([], {
        color: "red",
        weight: 3,
        className: "path",
      }).addTo(map);

      function start() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        intv = setInterval(() => {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);
        }, 1000);
      }

      function getPosition(position) {
        // console.log(position)
        const { latitude, longitude, accuracy } = position.coords;
        const pos = [latitude, longitude];
        //const pos = turf.randomPosition([49, 23, 43, 20])
        trackingPath.push(pos);
        polyline.addLatLng(pos);
        map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
        console.log(
          "Your coordinate is: Lat: " +
            latitude +
            " Long: " +
            longitude +
            " Accuracy: " +
            accuracy
        );
      }

      exportButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("trackingPath", trackingPath);
        save("data.txt", JSON.stringify(trackingPath));
      });

      function save(filename, data) {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" });
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
          const elem = window.document.createElement("a");
          elem.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          elem.download = filename;
          document.body.appendChild(elem);
          elem.click();
          document.body.removeChild(elem);
        }
      }

      function addMarker(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("add marker");
        status.innerText = "adding marker...";
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          const { latitude, longitude, accuracy } = position.coords;
          const pos = [latitude, longitude];

          var marker = L.marker(pos, {
            icon: new L.DivIcon({
              className: "marker",
              html: `<img src="/marker.svg" alt="" />
                                        <span contenteditable>click to edit</span>`,
            }),
          }).addTo(map);
          var Overlaymaps = {
            Marker: marker,
          };
          L.control.layers(Overlaymaps).addTo(map);

          status.innerText = `Marker added at ${pos.join(", ")}`;
        });
      }

      function startTracking(e) {
        status.innerText = "Started tracking...";
        e.preventDefault();
        start();
      }

      function stopTracking(e) {
        status.innerText = "Stopped tracking.";
        e.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(intv);
      }

      document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startTracking);
      document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopTracking);
      document.getElementById("marker").addEventListener("click", addMarker);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm just guessing here but I think for "current speed" I'd have to take the last 2 readings (every 1 second) and calculate distance and time passed to get speed. as for average speed I'd just take the first and the last data points and do the same.

Total distance I'd have to add up all the data points I assume since a path is not always a straight line.

I just have no idea how to do all this using gps coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet provides a useful [`latlngA.distanceTo(latlngB)` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto) to convert a pair of GPS coordinates into actual distance:

> Returns the distance (in meters) to the given LatLng calculated using the Spherical Law of Cosines.

With this, you can do something like:

```js
let totalElapsedTime = 0;
let totalDistance = 0;
let previousTime;
let previousLatLng;

function getPosition(position) {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const currentLatLng = L.latLng(
    position.coords.latitude,
    position.coords.longitude
  );

  // Skip first point (no computation is possible)
  if (previousTime && previousLatLng) {
    const elapsedTime = (currentTime.getTime() - previousTime.getTime()) / 1000; // In seconds
    const distance = previousLatLng.distanceTo(currentLatLng);

    const currentSpeed = distance / elapsedTime; // In meters / second

    totalElapsedTime += elapsedTime;
    totalDistance += distance;

    const averageSpeed = totalDistance / totalElapsedTime; // In meters / second
  }

  // Record time and position for next computation
  previousTime = currentTime;
  previousLatLng = currentLatLng;

  // Graphic stuff...
}
```

Note: for average speed you also need total travelled distance to account for non straight line path, unless you want to compute "flying distance" irrespective of actual path, which can therefore decrease back to 0 in case the path becomes a loop back to starting point.

Comment: getTime() returns ms...wouldn't we want to mulitply by 1000 not divide? to get seconds?

Comment: https://www.unitconverters.net/time/milliseconds-to-seconds.htm

Comment: So to get per hour it would be 1000 / 60 / 60?

Comment: Exactly! DurationInMs / msPerSecond / secondsPerMinute / minutesPerHour = durationInHour

Comment: Hello. This is interesting but I have a "<a class='gotoLine' href='#166:37'>166:37</a> Uncaught TypeError: previousLatLng.distanceTo is not a function" returned

I just changed the function getPosition(position) like you did and inserted the 4 "let" just before

Comment: Hi @VincentDc, please feel free to ask a new question with specific details of your issue. It is difficult to provide relevant help with these few indications only.

Comment: @ghybs Hello, I could start a new question but I had to say I can't find this very code posted as an answer, working. So I'm not sure this is a new question https://jsfiddle.net/vincedchart/01f8rjzb/1/

Comment: @VincentDc: ok I see what you mean. It is true that above answer explains the algorithm for requested computations, rather than is a black box drop-in replacement. So it may still need some adjustments to exactly fit into another code. Please feel free to edit it, or to post your fix as an answer, or ask a new question if you need help.

Comment: @ghybs ok, so I've put it into https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438158/get-current-and-average-speed-leaflet

Comment: @ghybs I'm being bullied here for asking questions and trying to learn. "You can’t post new questions right now
It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!

You've asked 5 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely."

Comment: I am sincerely sorry that you feel this way. You might miss some basics of programming, which makes the communication much more difficult and builds up misunderstanding. I will try to improve the above answer when I get time.